# How to fix Veracode error for InnerHtml

Tags: c#, html, htmlcontrols

When running Veracode, it generated a bunch of errors pointing to the lines with `InnerHtml`.

For example, one of those lines is:

```
objUL.InnerHtml += "<tr><td></td><td  class=\"libraryEdit\">" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(dtitems.Rows[currentitem]["content"].ToString()) + "</td>";
```

What do alternatives exist to fix it without using html server controls?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do, and what exactly does Veracode say?

Most likely, it is complaining that you could end up with an arbitrary code injection vulnerability if the data passed into your InnerHtml is untrusted and could contain malicious JavaScript.

The tool may not complain if you manually construct the DOM elements using the JavaScript `createElement` function to build each DOM element manually.

Comment: It complains with the following message:`Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS)` and I need to fix it before we run VeraCode again

Comment: Yes, this is basically a false-positive in the tool. It's complaining that you're injecting HTML using the innerHTML function, which doesn't sanitize content, and thus there's a security risk. There is a *legitimate* security risk if the `content` field contains attacker-supplied content and there are any bugs in the `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` function.

Comment: That depends on how you define *good approaches*. Using `createElement("td")` will allow you to create a TD that you can add to your DOM, and you can then set its `textContent` property with the untrusted data.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue in my ASP.NET Webforms application. The fix to this is relatively simple.

Install HtmlSanitizationLibrary from NuGet Package Manager and refer this in your application. 
At the code behind, please use the sanitizer class in the following way.

For example if the current code looks something like this,

```
YourHtmlElement.InnerHtml = "Your HTML content" ;
```

Then, replace this with the following:

```
string unsafeHtml = "Your HTML content"; 
YourHtmlElement.InnerHtml = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtml(unsafeHtml);
```

This fix will remove the Veracode vulnerability and make sure that the string gets rendered as HTML. Encoding the string at code behind will render it as 'un-encoded string' rather than RAW HTML as it is encoded before the render begins.